# C++ loop while issue

Tags: c++, while-loop

I am trying to write code to display an `int` which should be between 5 and 15. I have written the code below:

```
int main()
{
    int num;

    cout << "Enter a number ";
    cin >> num;

    if (num < 100)
        cout << "Please enter a number 5 or higher" << endl;
    if ((num > 5) && (num <= 15))
        cout << "you number is" << number << endl;
    if (num > 15)
        cout << "Please enter a number 15 or lower" << endl;
    {
    while (num < 5);
    cout << "Enter a number ";

    return 0;

}
```

I am having trouble with the `while` statement.

If I enter in 5, I need to say `you need to enter a valid number`, but the `while` loop is not looping back to the top, it'll say `please enter in a number` and I'm unable to enter in any numbers.  I'm confused.

Comment: I know the middle part needs to be num as the variable

Comment: Side note: user name reminded me of one nice library - https://github.com/mattdiamond/fuckitjs (which may need to be ported to C++ to get any random text to run :))

Comment: yeah wasn't helpful @AlexeiLevenkov

Answer (score 1):

You make two errors with your while-loop. First of all, you immediately close your while-loop with the semicolon: `while (num < 5);`. Next, if the given number is not in the interval `[5, 15]` you want to repeat the entire code including the part that shows the messages. Since you want to execute the part that asks for a number at least once you can also use a do-while loop.

If you really want a different message for a too small or large number you can use this code (not tested).

```
int main() 
{
  int const numMin = 5;
  int const numMax = 15;
  int num;

  cout << "Enter a number between " << numMin << " and " << numMax << ": ";

  do
  {
    cin >> num;

    if (num < numMin)
       cout << "Please enter a number " << numMin << " or higher\n";

    else if (num > numMax)
       cout << "Please enter a number " << numMax << " or lower\n";

  } while (num < numMin or num > numMax);

  cout << "You gave me the number " << num << endl;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The correct syntax for a while loop is:

```
while (condition)
{
actions if conditions are met
}
```

Below I have a condensed version of this code that should work. Since you wanted only a number between 5 and 15, you need to make sure it is > 5 not >= 5 or < 15 not <= 15.

```
int main()
{
int num;
cout<<"Please enter a number between 5 and 15: "<<endl;
cin>>num;
while (!(num>5 && num<15))
{
     cout<<"You need to enter a valid number: "<<endl;
     cin >> num;
}
cout << "Your number is : "<<num<<endl;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is not even close to being correct.  It should look more like this instead:

```
int num;

cout << "Enter a number ";
do
{
    cin >> num;
    if ((num >= 5) && (num <= 15))
        break;

    cout << "Please enter a number between 5 and 15" << endl;
}
while (1);

cout << "your number is " << num << endl;
```

Answer (score 0):

See this:

```
int main() 
{
    int num;
    cout<<"Enter a number:";
    cin>>num;
    while(!(num>=5 && num<=15))
    {
        cout<<"\nEnter a number between 5 and 15:";
        cin>>num;
    }
    cout<<"\nYour number is:"<<num;
    return 0;
}
```